# Remove ONE of the checkboxes from the Gift Message on Order Level?

Tags: checkout, messages

I enabled the Gift Messages on Order Level by going to System > Configuration > Sales > Sales > Gift Options. Now - the Gift message shows up on the delivery page during the checkout process but it requires (unnecessarily) the customer to click on two check-marks before they get to the actual text field to fill in the their gift message.

Is there a way to remove one of those checkmarks? I will never be using Gift messages on product level - just store level!

Thank you! :-*

Answer (score 1):

The template that shows the gift messages in the checkout process is `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/giftmessage/inline.phtml`. This template has some checks around the different check boxes. Around the message per item option is the function call `$this->isItemsAvailable`

This function simply counts the number of items in the current quote.

```
/**
 * Check if items are available
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isItemsAvailable()
{
    return count($this->getItems()) > 0;
}
```

One thing you could do is to rewrite this block and then change this function to always return false or extend it to be turned on and off via the admin config.

But since you say you will never use the section your easiest option would be to copy the template to your theme directory and then simply edit it to show only the sections you need.

Comment: Hi David - thank you so much for your answer - I really really appreciate it. I found the code in /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/giftmessage/inline.phtml And I see the section where these checkmarks are. What would be the benefit of copying these to my theme folder? It seems that when I make changes in the 'base' it shows on the front-end. The thing is-I am not able to correct the code so that it works..Probably a 2 minute thing for someone as smart as you but I already spent hours and hours trying to figure it out. :-( And it seems so simple-just show the field after one checkmark

Comment: @Allysin you should have templates in your theme as if you make changes to base and then upgrade your Magento system they will be overridden.